# How to use @ in git commit without it becoming a link/tag?

Tags: git, github

I used used the 'at' symbol in a git commit and unintentionally tagged a github user.

How can `@` be used in a git commit without it being interpreted as a tag?

Comment: The same way you used here: \`@\`.

Comment: I would be tempted to (only partly) snarkily answer "use bitbucket", but sometimes one cannot choose the git platform to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This interpretation of '@' is a feature of Github, not `git`. Specifically it's in [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/en/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#mentioning-people-and-teams). It cannot be turned off.

So either you don't use the character or you don't use Github (or any other platform that uses and extends Markdown… which is hard to find, all of them these days follow GH lead).

You can [escape '@' with a backslash](https://help.github.com/en/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#ignoring-markdown-formatting): `\@`